# Uploading image iOS to PHP with MKNetworkEngine - I know it works, but cannot get PHP to capture

Tags: php, ios, file-upload, upload, mknetworkengine

I created an iOS application which uploads an image taken by the camera to a server using the `MKNetworkEngine`, [as outlined in the following tutorial](http://www.michaelroling.com/post/upload-an-image-using-objective-c)
If I set the host to **posttestserver.com**, a public POST testing server as the name suggests, it returns a URL and the path to the newly uploaded photo. Success!

**Problem:** I am unable to use my own PHP code to capture that file and save it on my webserver. I dont understand how **posttestserver.com** is successful in getting it, but my very straightforward php is not.

**iOS side:**

```
NSData *image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage], 0.1);

NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"woody", @"userName", @"testPassword", @"password", nil];

 //WORKS:
self.flUploadEngine = [[fileUploadEngine alloc] initWithHostName:@"posttestserver.com" customHeaderFields:dic];
 //Doesnt work:
self.flUploadEngine = [[fileUploadEngine alloc] initWithHostName:@"camerademander.com" customHeaderFields:dic]; 

NSMutableDictionary *postParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"testApp", @"appID",
                                   nil];
self.flOperation = [self.flUploadEngine postDataToServer:postParams path:@"/users/recieveStub3.php"];
[self.flOperation addData:image forKey:@"userfile" mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"upload.jpg"];

[self.flOperation addCompletionHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation* operation) {
    NSLog(@"HTTP 200: success");
    NSLog(@"%@", [operation responseString]);
}
                          errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *errorOp, NSError* error) {
                              NSLog(@"%@", error);
                              UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                              message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                                             delegate:nil
                                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
                              [alert show];
                          }];

[self.flUploadEngine enqueueOperation:self.flOperation];
```

**php:**

```
echo "Connected to server successfully.";
$uploaddir = '/photos/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['upload.jpg']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['upload.jpg'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Successfully uploaded! :{$file}:";
}
```

This blocks my project from moving forward - I don't understand how posttestserver is able to get a result but I am not, especially when I am able to successfully connect to my own php and server.

Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your iOS side,change the key "userfl" to "userfile"

```
[self.flOperation addData:image forKey:@"userfile" mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"upload.jpg"];
```

In your php side,you should chang your code like this:

```
echo "Connected to server successfully.";
$uploaddir = '/photos/';
$file = basename($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir.$file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Successfully uploaded! :{$file}:";
}
```

I'm not a PHP Programmer, after look at [w3schools's PHP File Upload Tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp), write the answer, hope it works :)

**UPTATE:**

ok,updated my answer to get more info for your qusetion.(I have test on my server,it works well)

1. delete the photos dir if exits
2. use the php code below and see what you get

   ```
   if($_FILES){
       $uploaddir = './photos/';
       $file = basename($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]);
       $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$file;

       if(!file_exists($uploaddir)){
         if(!mkdirs($uploaddir)){
           echo "Fail to creat uploaddir";
           exit();
         }
       }else if( file_exists($uploadfile)){
          echo "Upload file exists";
          exit();
       }

       if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $uploadfile)) {
           echo "Successfully uploaded! :{$file}:";
       }else{
           echo "Failed uploaded! :{$file}:";
       }
   }else {
       echo "Uploaded empty file";
   }

   function mkdirs($dir, $mode = 0777) {

       if (is_dir ( $dir ) || @mkdir ( $dir, $mode ))
           return TRUE;
       if (!mkdirs ( dirname ( $dir ), $mode ))
           return FALSE;
       return @mkdir ( $dir, $mode );

   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that typo, but thats not the root cause of the issue - I run this, I get the feedback "connected to server successfully" but nothing more.

Comment: The solution to my specific problem I added below.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a server permission issue - I used `echo $file, is_writable($file) ? ' is writable' : ' is NOT readable', "\n";` to determine this.